# Выбор строк в массиве numpy по условию

Tags: python, numpy

Есть двумерный массив numpy

```
arr = np.arange(18).reshape((-1, 6))

    [[ 0  1  1  3  4  5]
     [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
     [12 13 14 15 16 17]]
```

Нужно отобрать строки, в которых все элементы  начиная с 3го элемента > a.
Например для a = 9 останется  только

```
[[12 13 14 15 16 17]]
```

А для a = 7

```
[[ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]]
```

Как это сделать не перебирая каждую строку в цикле?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

делаем выборку элементов `arr[:, 2:]` и проверяем, что они все больше a

```
arr[(arr[:, 2:] > a).all(axis=1)]
```